# Nested loops in XSLT for dynamically building XML

Tags: xslt, loops, dynamic, nested

I am getting an XML document output from Cognos which I want to use as Input for Crystal reports.
However, the XML format needed by Crystal Report is different from the XML format of Cognos output.

I am trying to transform the Input XML document (Cognos) using XSLT to get desired XML for Crystal.

Having set the context, below is the Input XML coming from Cognos:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataset>
<metadata>
    <item Name="EmpId" />
    <item Name="EmpName" />
    <item Name="DeptName" />
</metadata>
<data>
    <rows>
        <row>
            <value>1</value>
            <value>John</value>
            <value>Finance</value>
        </row>
        <row>
            <value>2</value>
            <value>Peter</value>
            <value>Admin</value>
        </row>
    </rows>
</data>
```

Desired XML format required by Crystal Report:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataset>
<row>
    <EmpId>1</EmpId>
    <EmpName>John</EmpName>
    <DeptName>Finance</DeptName>
</row>
<row>
    <EmpId>2</EmpId>
    <EmpName>Peter</EmpName>
    <DeptName>Admin</DeptName>
</row>
</dataset>
```

I have written below XSLT for the desired transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<dataset>
<xsl:for-each select="./dataset/data/rows/row">
    <row>
        <xsl:for-each select="/dataset/metadata/item">
            <xsl:element name="{@Name}">
                <xsl:for-each select="/dataset/data/rows/row/value">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:for-each>                 
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>             
    </row>
</xsl:for-each>
</dataset>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting below Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<dataset>
<row>
    <EmpId>1JohnFinance2PeterAdmin</EmpId>
    <EmpName>1JohnFinance2PeterAdmin</EmpName>
    <DeptName>1JohnFinance2PeterAdmin</DeptName>
</row>
<row>
    <EmpId>1JohnFinance2PeterAdmin</EmpId>
    <EmpName>1JohnFinance2PeterAdmin</EmpName>
    <DeptName>1JohnFinance2PeterAdmin</DeptName>
</row>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After customizing the solution provided by [@DimitreNovatchev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404116/nested-loops-in-xslt-for-dynamically-building-xml/12405943#12405943) I was able to get the desired transformation of XML.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataset  xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<metadata>
    <item name="Employee Id" />
    <item name="Employee Name" />
    <item name="Department Name" />
</metadata>
<data>      
    <row>
        <value>1</value>
        <value Salutation="Dr." >John</value>
        <value>Finance</value>
    </row>
    <row>
        <value>2</value>
        <value Salutation="Mr." >Peter</value>
        <value>Admin</value>
    </row>      
</data>
```

**XSLT Transformation**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:c="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:variable name="vNames" select="/*/c:metadata/*/@name" />
<xsl:template match="/*/c:data">
<dataset>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</dataset>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="c:row">
<row>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</row>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="c:row/*">
<xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
<xsl:element name="{translate($vNames[$vPos], ' ', '_')}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*">
<xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
    <xsl:value-of select="." />
</xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

</xsl:stylesheet>

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<dataset xmlns:c="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/">
<row>
    <Employee_Id>1</Employee_Id>
    <Employee_Name Salutation="Dr.">John</Employee_Name>
    <Department_Name>Finance</Department_Name>
</row>
<row>
    <Employee_Id>2</Employee_Id>
    <Employee_Name Salutation="Mr.">Peter</Employee_Name>
    <Department_Name>Admin</Department_Name>
</row>
```

Comment: Thanks this helped me conform Cognos Report Studio data exported to XML. One Note However: **Input XML** is missing '</dataset>' at the end and the **XSLT Transformation** is missing '</xsl:stylesheet>' at the end. The [online xslt tester tool](https://xslttest.appspot.com) was giving me _XML document structures must start and end within the same entity_ errors until I corrected

Answer (score 5):

**This short and simple transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vNames" select="/*/metadata/*/@Name"/> 

 <xsl:template match="/*/data">
     <dataset><xsl:apply-templates/></dataset>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="row">
  <row><xsl:apply-templates/></row>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="row/*">
  <xsl:variable name="vPos" select="position()"/>
  <xsl:element name="{$vNames[$vPos]}"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:element>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (added a missing closing tag to make it well-formed):

```
<dataset>
    <metadata>
        <item Name="EmpId" />
        <item Name="EmpName" />
        <item Name="DeptName" />
    </metadata>
    <data>
        <rows>
            <row>
                <value>1</value>
                <value>John</value>
                <value>Finance</value>
            </row>
            <row>
                <value>2</value>
                <value>Peter</value>
                <value>Admin</value>
            </row>
        </rows>
    </data>
</dataset>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<dataset>
   <row>
      <EmpId>1</EmpId>
      <EmpName>John</EmpName>
      <DeptName>Finance</DeptName>
   </row>
   <row>
      <EmpId>2</EmpId>
      <EmpName>Peter</EmpName>
      <DeptName>Admin</DeptName>
   </row>
</dataset>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Using templates and the XSLT template selection mechanism to do the job. As a rule in XSLT we prefer **[`xsl:apply-templates`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#element-apply-templates)** to **[`xsl:for-each`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#element-for-each)** -- thus getting simpler, more extensible, more understandable and maintainable code. This is an example of an almost 100% "push style" solution.
2. Using **[`xsl:variable`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#element-variable)** to get (once and forever) the nodes we will be constantly working with.
3. Saving **[`position()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-position)** in a variable for later use in other contexts -- `position()` is context-dependent.

Comment: Hello Dimitre, is it better for the performance to write the Name-path into the variable `vNames` ?

Comment: @Peter, Sorry, what do you mean? Please, rephrase.

Comment: @Peter, Selecting the N-th node from a node-set is more efficient than evaluating a complex XPath expression having multiplr reverse steps -- every time we process a `value`.

Comment: @Peter: Both. Readability and convenience. Shorter and simpler. More flexible -- if the XPath expression selecting the necessary name needs to be changed (due to restructuring of the XML document), then I have to just change the XPath expression in one place (in the variable definition) only. All remaining code will be untouched.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, Thanks for the solution as well as the explanation. However, I removed `code`omit-xml-declaration="yes" to get `code` <?xml version="1.0"?> `code` in the output XML.

Comment: @Fun2Learn, Sure, if you like it so. This declaration contains the default value for the version of XML and isn't necessary at all.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, A small problem. Input XML will have following two XMLNamespaces in the root node `code`<dataset xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"> `code`. With this new change, the suggested transformation do not work. When I tried checking the namespaces one at a time, I found that only the below namespace is creating problem: `code`xmlns="http://developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"`code`. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Fun2Learn, This is the most FAQ in XPath and XSLT. Search about XPath and default namespace and you'll get many good answers. If you still don't understand them, please, ask a new, separate question. Very shortly, you need to define in the XSLT code (on the `xsl:stylesheet` element a namespace, say: `xmlns:x="developer.cognos.com/schemas/xmldata/1/"` and then in any XPath expression prefix any element name with `x:`. So, `/*/metadata/*/@Name` will become: `/*/x:metadata/*/@Name` -- do this same change on all element names -- then the new transformation will work with this XML (with default ns

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, Thanks for the hint. I did search for it and got similar suggestion as you mentioned above. However, due to my weak fundamentals of XML and XML namespaces was not able to make it work. It is working as expected after prefixing all the elements with `code` x: `code`.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev, You are absolutely correct that I didn't apply the namespaces properly. It may sound silly but I wrongly prefixed the elements with `code` x:/*/metadata/*/@Name `code` instead of `code` /*/x:metadata/*/@Name `code`. After correcting, its working absolutely fine. Thanks a ton for your support

Comment: I came across a special scenario where attribute values in Input XML can start with Number, Special Character or Space, which breaks above solution.

`<dataset>
<metadata>
    <item name="1Employee Id" />
    <item name=" Employee Name" />
    <item name="$Department Name" />
</metadata>
<data>
<row>
    <value>1</value>
    <value>John</value>
    <value>Finance</value>
</row>
</data>
</dataset>`

Since Element names cannot start with Number or Space, how can I replace those characters with some valid characters for Element name say _ or C_ to get the same desired Output XML. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `<template>` and `<apply-templates>` mechanism to solve this problem. `For-each` is not the right way to go here I think.

XML input:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<dataset>
<metadata>
    <item Name="EmpId" />
    <item Name="EmpName" />
    <item Name="DeptName" />
</metadata>
<data>
    <rows>
        <row>
            <value>1</value>
            <value>John</value>
            <value>Finance</value>
        </row>
        <row>
            <value>2</value>
            <value>Peter</value>
            <value>Admin</value>
        </row>
    </rows>
</data>
</dataset>
```

apply this stylesheet to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <dataset>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//row"/>
    </dataset>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <row>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="value"/>
    </row>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="value">
    <xsl:variable name="index">
        <xsl:number/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="{../../../../metadata/item[position() = $index]/@Name}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you get this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dataset>
<row>
    <EmpId>1</EmpId>
    <EmpName>John</EmpName>
    <DeptName>Finance</DeptName>
</row>
<row>
    <EmpId>2</EmpId>
    <EmpName>Peter</EmpName>
    <DeptName>Admin</DeptName>
</row>
</dataset>
```

The `dataset` and `row` elements I create by matching and applying certain templates.

Comment: You could possibly make use of an **xsl:key** here, to make the looking up of the element name a bit more tidy, and more efficient.

Comment: Peter, Instead of using `//row` as a match pattern, it is simpler (and equivalent) to use just: `row`.

Comment: Thank you Dimitre for that hint but if I run the above XSL with `row`the output XML is empty, it seems it needs the `//`.

Comment: @Peter, I am talking only about the *match pattern*, not about the `select` attribute of `xsl:apply-templates`

Comment: Using position() is likely to be more efficient than using xsl:number, especially as xsl:number is inside a result tree fragment, which means you are converting a number to a string to a tree held in the variable, and when you reference the variable you are converting it first to a string and finally back to a number.

Comment: Thank you Michael, I learn something every day at stackoverflow.

Comment: @Prashant, you are welcome. Dimitre's solution in this case is the one to use though (better readability, convenience and efficiency)