# XSLT 1.0: put conditions into match attribute or apply-templates?

Tags: templates, xslt, apply-templates

I have a general question regarding `<xsl:template match="">` and `<xsl:apply-templates/>`.

I have the case where I match the element `E1EDP01`. But no all `E1EDP01` elements should be matched, only a certain range.

But now what is the correct way of matching only a certain range of elements?

**Is it correct to do it this way:**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="E1EDP01"/>
```

and the template that restricts the range of `E1EDP01`:

```
<xsl:template match="E1EDP01[not(PSTYV='ZDAE')][E1EDP02[QUALF='001']/ZEILE]">
...
</xsl:template>
```

**Or do I have to change the apply-templates to:**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="E1EDP01[not(PSTYV='ZDAE')][E1EDP02[QUALF='001']/ZEILE]"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both work, but they express slightly different intentions.  The specific matching template says "this is how you should always process *this kind of* `E1EDP01` element", and the `<xsl:apply-templates select="E1EDP01"/>` says "process all my `E1EDP01` elements now".  Whereas having a generic template and a specific apply says "I want to process *these particular* `E1EDP01` elements now (but I might want to process others later)" and "this is how you process any `E1EDP01`".

Which approach is better really depends on whether the `[not(PSTYV='ZDAE')][E1EDP02[QUALF='001']/ZEILE]` is something inherent to the way the elements should be handled, or something specific to what you want to do at one particular place in the stylesheet.  For example, if I had some XML describing financial transactions and I had a rule that negative amounts always had to be displayed in a red box, then I might define

```
<xsl:template match="amount[. &lt; 0]">
  <redbox><xsl:value-of select="."/></redbox>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="amount"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:template>
```

If instead I wanted to include a summary redbox with all the negative amounts, but display the amounts normally elsewhere then I would probably choose to use a single template for `amount` but then filter at the `apply-templates` point

```
<redbox>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="amount[. &lt; 0]" />
</redbox>
```

You have to choose the approach that makes most sense for your task.

Comment: Hello Ian, thank you for your detailed answer. Yes, they both work. I was wondering if one might also be to prefer due to performance issues? I do not really understand what you mean in your second paragraph though. I do something specific with all E1EDP02 elements that match the criteria, all the others are not considered. Could you explain the 2nd paragraph again please? Thank you, Peter PS: for example the comment from Dimitre under here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12404116/nested-loops-in-xslt-for-dynamically-building-xml/12405591#12405591 to not use // in the match-pattern.

Comment: Hello Ian, thank you for your edit. I think I will go with filtering at the <xsl:apply-templates> because I specifically only want a certain range to be processed (in your example into the <redbox>). I think I got it. Best regards, Peter +1

Answer (score 1):

If both work for what you're trying to do, just pick the one that makes the most sense for your XSLT.